# QuickAction in a Dialog

Tags: android, quickaction

I´ve working with quickaction since i read in a thread (http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)
Everything was working ok, but i tried to use it in a dialog and it didn't work.
[Dialog with quickaction](http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/9372/sc201112200950161.jpg)
I think the problem is in the "show" method of quickaction, because it's using an "anchor" to set the position of the quickaction. Does anyone have a problem like this???How did you solve it?

Comment: i've face the same issue ... just add issue here https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction/issues

Comment: I can't answer my own question but i found the solution :)!!!You just need to change this line in show method "anchor.getLocationOnScreen(location);" instead of that you need to use "anchor.getLocationInWindow(location);" :)